# Center an inline element that is a button

Tags: html, css, center

I was making a button, and it was completely fine and centered until i discovered a glitch where I could click anywhere on that line to go to index.html (the button was linking to index.html). My first idea was to change the `display` attribute  to inline opposed to block. Yet, the inline button won't center.

**Code I had before:**

```
.back {
  color: black;
  border-color: black;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 6px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 35px;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.back:hover {
  transition-duration: .4s;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

**Code I have now:**

```
.back {
  color: black;
  border-color: black;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 6px;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 35px;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.back:hover {
  transition-duration: .4s;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

See, it's exactly the same except for the inline. 
Useful note: I did look up 'how to center a button' and I tried the w3schools way, but that just produced a big visual glitch. 
 Here's the HTML 
**HTML:** 
`<a href="index.html"><button class="back">Back to homepage</button><a>`

FIXED: left: 35%, position: absolute;

Comment: Using `display: inline-block` for a button is always best practise, outside the button it is an inline button and inside the button it is a block element. Then inside you can use more vertical css like height, padding-top/bottom, etc. Outside the button it is the inline element you want to use.

Comment: OK lemme try :)

Comment: hhhmm, how can that center it? Also, oddly, on index.html I used a .menu class and it has the exact same attributes, meaning it's a problem with the html

Comment: Did you give the parent of the button a `text-align: center`

Comment: if using the block, then the solution is `.back { display: block; width: 30%; margin: 0 auto; }`

Comment: I fixed it with position: absolute;, and left: 35% :)